# Git Bash script to check whether repo has any commits?

Tags: git, bash

I have a script that i need to act differently based on if there are any, that is one or more, commits. What is the best way to do this?

In pseudo code it would look something like this..

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ `git log_count` == "0" ]]; then
    echo "No commits exist for this repo."
    # Do stuff..
else
    echo "One or more commits do exist!"
    # Do other stuff
fi
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You could also check the result of:

```
git rev-parse --verify HEAD
```

(after [this thread](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/9/8/3228604):)

> 1. It's a plumbing command, and so less likely to change its behavior
>       versus "`git diff`".
> 2. The seems more obvious to me. `rev-parse --verify` is meant to ask
>       "is this a valid object name?"
>
> It is slightly different from your `show-ref`.
>   Yours asks "is there anything in refs/heads in this repository?"
>   Mine asks "does the current `HEAD` exist?"
>
> In practice, they are both reasonable tests, since once you have a branch, it is very difficult to get `HEAD` to point to something invalid short of editing manually to some bogus value. But you might prefer one over the other depending on what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

The trivial from the top of my head is

```
$ git log | egrep -c  "^commit"
1493
```